# Is there a quantitative definition of a Quiet, Moderate or Accelerate market conditions?

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, statistical-finance, behavioral-finance, structured-finance

i know the StdDev price technical indicator  which is the standard deviation but this one has an absolute value.

The market conditions are:

- Quiet: lower oscillation of price around a constant value.
- Moderate :variation of price is constant.
- Accelerate : variation of price is non constant (accelerated).

So Is there any other quantitative definition of a Quiet, Moderate or Accelerate market conditions with a comprehensive scale?